# How do we avoid having our website being categorized by Fortiguard as phishing?

Tags: web-development, filtering, phishing

Fortiguard web filtering changes the category of our website from Information Technology to Phishing for no apparent reason. When it is categorized as Phishing, it gets blocked by Fortiguard. FortiGuard Web Filtering Service is quick to change the category from Phishing back to Information Technology when requested. So how do we avoid having our website being categorized by Fortiguard as phishing at all?

I've used the following websites to confirm that our site isn't on any blacklists:

https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/

https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing

Our website is a Wordpress website and we have enabled auto-updates of all our plug-ins.